# Is there an easier way to do this in C#? (null-coalescing type question)

Tags: c#, null, if-statement, null-coalescing-operator

Is there an easier way to do this?

```
string s = i["property"] != null ? "none" : i["property"].ToString();
```

notice the difference between it and null-coalesce (??) is that the not-null value (first operand of ?? op) is accessed before returning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following

```
string s = (i["property"] ?? "none").ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

If indexer returns `object`:

```
(i["property"] ?? (object)"none").ToString()
```

or just:

```
(i["property"] ?? "none").ToString()
```

If `string`:

```
i["property"] ?? "none"
```

Comment: +1 In this particular case `object ?? string` already widens correctly without the cast. (It's not specified that `i["property"]` *is* object though...)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatives for fun.

```
void Main()
{
 string s1 = "foo";
 string s2 = null;
 Console.WriteLine(s1.Coalesce("none"));
 Console.WriteLine(s2.Coalesce("none"));
 var coalescer = new Coalescer<string>("none");
 Console.WriteLine(coalescer.Coalesce(s1));
 Console.WriteLine(coalescer.Coalesce(s2));
}
public class Coalescer<T>
{
    T _def;
    public Coalescer(T def) { _def = def; }
    public T Coalesce(T s) { return s == null ? _def : s; }
}
public static class CoalesceExtension
{
    public static string Coalesce(this string s, string def) { return s ?? def; }
}
```

Comment: +1 For the time to post. However, one problem with approaches like this is that some operators (`&&`, `||`, `??`, `?:`, etc) are lazy. In this case the argument to the Coalesce function is eagerly-evaluated. It doesn't matter here, but it might. Imagine `"none"` is really `Foo(x)`. This can be addressed with taking in a lambda/func, but C# syntax doesn't do any magical/automatic lifting to such so it can quickly become cumbersome.